# isalnum() in python not giving expected results

Tags: python-3.x

```
string = "xyz123"
print(string.isalnum()) # this returns 'True'

string = "xy 12" 
print(string.isalnum()) # this returns 'False'

string = "xy" 
print(string.isalnum()) # this return 'True'
```

But 'xy' is not alphanumeric.
Python version 3.6.4

Comment: `xy 12` returns False, because `white space` is not alphanumeric but `xy` is. 

...


```str.isalnum()
Return True if all characters in the string are alphanumeric and there is at least one character, False otherwise. A character c is alphanumeric if one of the following returns True: c.isalpha(), c.isdecimal(), c.isdigit(), or c.isnumeric().

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isalnum#str.isalnum
```

Answer (score 0):

As @BugHunter has pointed out, `isalnum()` may not be helpful in your case.

You can try:

`bool(re.match('^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])', string))`

Answer (score 0):

Alphanumeric means consisting of either letters and numbers or both, so that is why you received that output. Whitespace is not alphanumeric hence why it is false.